# How to add Cache-Control: in a Nuxtjs app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, cache-control

I want to add Cache-Control: to my Nuxtjs app. it's a Universal nuxtjs app and I have many external scripts like- google analytics, razorpay etc etc.
basically I am trying to improve my performance in lighthouse. And there are 12 external srcipts files on which it's saying - "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy".

So, do I have to add the Cache-Control: in nuxt.config.js? if yes, then how?

Comment: did you check if that external scripts has an cache? `Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy` could also mean that the cache expire date is very short

Comment: Yes I have checked. Some scripts/file have it and some of them don't. I have very confused with this

Comment: do you run some reverse proxy infront of your application?

Comment: No, absolutely not\

Comment: ok so, did you plan how you deploy your app?

Comment: it's already deployed. :)

Comment: well fact is that you cant set an cache control from an external link, you will need to host the external links on your own machine and set an cache control on your onw